# PushNotifications doesn't work after close App - FirefoxOS

Tags: push-notification, firefox-os

I'm developing an app in FirefoxOS that use PushNotifications
I followed the instructions in:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/SimplePush
and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Simple_Push

And All si OK, but just for the time I register the app, the moment I close the App and send a notification nothing happen, and never works again.

Why could this happen and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Without any code, I I would guess that it may have a problem with the manifest. Did you add

```
"messages": [
   { "push": "/index.html"},
   { "push-register": "/index.html"}
]
```

to it?

Comment: Yes, I do. Actually I cuold resolve it by moving all related with `mozSetMessageHandler` to a single js file, and called it before my app main js.

Comment: Awesome, glad you found the issue: you should post this as an answer.